# Why does my UITextView show up when I'm using the frame property but not when I'm using constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints, autolayout

I'm new to using constraints, so I'm not surprised I've gotten something wrong, but I can't figure out what I've done and/or how to fix it.

Here's my method using the `frame` property; it works fine and the text view shows up:

```
-(void)displayFeedbackText {
    feedback = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    feedback.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    feedback.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
    NSString *t = @"If you have any problems with the" + 16; //Longest line of text view + padding.
    float textWidth = [t sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14]].width;
    float textHeight = [t sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14]].height;
    feedback.text=@"Thank you for buying My Haiku! \nIf you have any problems with the \napp, or if you want to share any \nthoughts or suggestions, please \nemail me at joel@xxxxx.com.";
    feedback.editable=NO;
    feedback.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2-textWidth/2, (screenHeight/2-tabBarHeight) - (textHeight*6)/2, textWidth, textHeight*6);
    feedback.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    [self.view addSubview:feedback];
}
```

Here's the method using constraints (I've set `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` in `viewDidLoad`).  Nothing shows up:

```
-(void)displayFeedbackText {
    feedback = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    feedback.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    feedback.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
    feedback.text=@"Thank you for buying My Haiku! \nIf you have any problems with the \napp, or if you want to share any \nthoughts or suggestions, please \nemail me at joel@xxxxx.com.";
    feedback.editable=NO;
    feedback.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:feedback attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:feedback attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintX];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintY];
    [self.view addSubview:feedback];
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not showing up because you have no size constraints, so its size is probably zero. Try setting either explicit size constraints or ones relative to the superview. If they're explicit constraints, you do it like this (and similarly with a height constraint):

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthCon = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:feedback attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1  constant:320];
[feedback addConstraint:widthCon];
```